# Trying to reduce Amazon instance CPU usage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cpu-usage

I use a micro instance currently for my wordpress site. When I perform some data imports, usually 1-2 a day, my CPU spikes to 100% killing a website, otherwise it stays calm under 30%. I am looking for a solution to this.

I am new to AWS and my question may need more clarification..but could I just create another micro instance, enable autobalancer and CPU usage would go down? Or should I switch to SMALL instance instead of micro in order to reduce it? Obviously trying to reduce running costs too.

I would assume Small instance is more powerful than micro and maybe could handle CPU usage better. Howerever they charge more for it, so I wonder if I can solve this problem with 2 micro instances. Would that work? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, after a sober night of thinking I came up with a cheap and easy solution and basically answered my own question.

I created another micro instance (it's free for me for one year) from my original AMI image. So basically I have 2 identical wordpress sites connected to the same MySQL database and s3 account. I named my clone instance a 'WorkingMachine' :) Then I had to change WorkingMachine's config.php file home and siteurl in order to connect to the right admin site to the right instance. Finally, I can now run all the imports, cron jobs and other CPU expensive jobs from my WorkingMachine and leave an original instance untouched, for traffic only. To sum up, original instance for reads, Workingmachine is for writes. They both are micro instances. The best part is, that my WorkingMachine doesn't have to be up running 24/7, only when I do imports and other jobs. So I can upgrade that instance to Small or even more powerful machine (if I would need more CPU) and stop it when I don't need it. It's cheap. This took me like 10mins to setup up.

Answer (score 1):

Micro instances are unique within ec2. They use a burstable CPU profile which they will go up to 2 ECU, but then be limited to much lower than 1 (0.1-0.2 ECU) when the allotted burst time has been exceeded.

A small instance has 1 ECU of CPU time allocated to it all the time. I would recommend upgrading to a small instance and getting a heavy utilization reservation if you plan to keep it running all the time.

Comment: Does it mean I can't use autoscaling with micro instances? lets say I have 2 of them.. would it scale in terms of CPU?

Comment: Autoscaling within EC2 refers to horizontal scaling. It does not change attributes of the instance, instead it simply adds more instances. In order to use this effectively, your instances need to follow share nothing architecture. Something that wordpress is not designed for by default.